# Why does build fail due to missing apklib dependency with custom local repository?

Tags: android, scala, sbt, apklib

I have a Scala/Android project that I compile with SBT 0.12.4. It works.

I can declare a new repository and new `apklib` dependency:

```
resolvers +=  "local maven" at "file:./lib/"
libraryDependencies += apklib("com.sbstrm" % "appirater" % "1.3.1")
```

I've got the following files in `./lib/` of my project's root (that corresponds to the `local maven` resolver's definition):

Under `com/sbstrm/appirater`

- _maven.repositories
- appirater-1.3.1.apklib
- appirater-1.3.1.pom

and in `com/sbstrm/appirater/1.3.1`:

- maven-metadata-local.xml

The issues come when I upgrade sbt to 0.13.6.

With the version I'm getting the following errors and I can't embed the appirater library anymore in my project:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.sbstrm#appirater;1.3.1: URI is not hierarchical
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.sbstrm:appirater:1.3.1 (/project/build.sbt#L34-35)
[warn]        +- default:project_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.sbstrm#appirater;1.3.1: URI is not hierarchical
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:243)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:158)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:147)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:147)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:124)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:56)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:64)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:64)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:119)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:147)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:156)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1282)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1279)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$84.apply(Defaults.scala:1309)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$84.apply(Defaults.scala:1307)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1312)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1306)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1324)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1264)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1242)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.sbstrm#appirater;1.3.1: URI is not hierarchical
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Where does `apklib` come from? It's surely part of a plugin for Android development with sbt. Which one? That's where I'd look for answers.

Comment: comes from mvn install from the project here : https://github.com/drewjw81/appirater-android

Comment: I was asking about `apklib` method call to add the apklib to `libraryDependencies`. It's probably the [android-plugin](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin) plugin's thingy.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to make it work with sbt 0.13.2 so I chose to include the lib directly inside my src/java/com directory... however it works with another version of sbt.. maybe it s related to this too: addSbtPlugin("com.hanhuy.sbt" % "android-sdk-plugin" % "1.2.20") I have no idea... -> It makes no sense and the "URI is not hierarchical" error seems irrelevant here.

Comment: Why do you define `./lib` as a resolver?! The directory is on the classpath by default without being explicit about it in `build.sbt`. Just save `appirater-1.3.1.apklib` to `lib` and it should work. Unless you expect transitive dependency that won't work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `${baseDirectory.value}` to reference the project's main directory, i.e. `resolvers +=  "local maven" at s"file:${baseDirectory.value}/lib"`.

The issue comes from the line `resolvers +=  "local maven" at "file:./lib/"` because [the preconditions on the parameter do not hold](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.net.URI)), i.e. `"file:./lib/"` doesn't meet [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.net.URI))'s contract.

You can check it out yourself in Scala REPL:

```
new java.io.File(new java.net.URI("file:./lib/"))
```

With the above line you'll face the error:

```
scala> new java.io.File(new java.net.URI("file:./lib/"))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
  ... 43 elided
```

The solution is to use `${baseDirectory.value}` to fully reference the path of the main directory of the project:

```
resolvers +=  "local ./lib maven" at s"file:${baseDirectory.value}/lib"
```

Comment: I will give a try to your answer to validate it. However, it works with a more recent version of sbt with the syntax that I used in this post. By the way, I changed the folder name to maven_libs which is, indeed much better. About included folders: it depends on the sbt plugin you use actually, especially for jni projects.